# Visual studio 2017 professional attach to process not working correcly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have one solution in VS 2017 pro, where i am unable to attach process and debug properly.
For start, even though my application is loading/running properly, visual studio attach to process screen always shows 0 Sessions against that app-pool/application.

If i then select it, it never hits any of the C# code (weird).
I manage to hit some razor view cshtml files to be debugged, but never the c# code

any ideas?

Comment: add some code snippet please

Comment: Are you running VS as administrator?

Comment: @Prany not sure what difference it would make

Answer (score 0):

My first question if you have started process/service. Then build code do you get error message that exe is already in use?

- If not then you are not sure about the correct code.
- If then aleast run against your code alomst for sure.

If that not solve your problem. We need to see where you have installed and how to service. Also what the code for the service looks like. It help see where you have your first breakpoint in the code.

Usually if it not reaching the breakpoint or the code is grayed out. It is because the binary is not found or it does not match the code. T

The service you are trying to debug are it installed in your building directory so you are sure is lastes version?